# How to pass a file(csv) from JAVA desktop application as parameter to a web application?

Tags: javascript, java

A java Desktop application writes data to a csv file and stores locally. This file has to be read in WebBrowser using d3.js.

How do I pass the location of file from the java application to the web application ?

Answer (score 0):

Web application is deployed on server, where as Desktop applications are standalone.

**Solution 1:** 
If you want your web application to get the file path, you have to define a common location where your desktop application can put the file and web application can read it.

**Problem with the approach:**
But there is a problem of data in-consistency if your Desktop application is writing the file and at the same time your web application is trying to read it, it will lead the data into in-consistence state.

**Solution 2:** You can create a web-service in your web-application, which the desktop application can call once it finishes writing the file and pass that file to the web-service, which is than stored in your web-application. And you can use it as you like with out worrying about data integrity.

For reading CSV file in D3 you can use,

```
 d3.csv("/data/cities.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

**References:**
[REST Service in Java](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXmN3t1erMAhXIN48KHUnFBtIQFggdMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FREST%2Farticle.html&usg=AFQjCNHQFwJAf_H6EoN9kf9gV03pEyOFUA&bvm=bv.122448493,d.c2I) 
[Reading CSV in D3](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html) 
[CSV in D3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV)